# Why has my output for dot not been added? Then, when I print(dot), it shows the add __str__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Vector3D:
    def __init__(self, x, y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector3D(self.x + other.x , self.y + other.y , self.z + other.z)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Vector3D(self.x * other.x , self.y * other.y , self.z * other.z)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.__add__(self):
            return '[X = %.2f, Y = %.2f, Z = %.2f]' % (self.x , self.y, self.z)
        elif self.__mul__(self):
            return '%d' % (self.x + self.y + self.z)
        else:
            return 0

v1 = Vector3D(1,2,3)
v2 = Vector3D(4,5,6)
v3 = v1 + v2
print(v3)
dot = v1 * v2
print(dot)
```

Why has my output for dot not been added? Then, when I call `print(dot)`, it shows the add `__str__`?

```
"[X=5.00,Y=7.00,Z=9.00]"
"32"
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to do in `__str__`; `if self.__add__(self)` is same as `v1 + v1` which will almost always be `True` and thus `__str__` will return the first `return`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not sure why the `__str__` func is invoking add and mul, but I think you just want to stringify the vector with `return '[X = %.2f, Y = %.2f, Z = %.2f]' % (self.x , self.y, self.z)`.

Comment: `bool(self.__add__(self))` -> `True`.

Comment: What exact output are you getting that is unexpected? When I run it I end up with [X = 5.00, Y = 7.00, Z = 9.00]
[X = 4.00, Y = 10.00, Z = 18.00] as the output, which seems fine

Comment: You need to check for some instance variable which is set to specific values when `__add__` or `__mul__` is called

Comment: "[X=5.00,Y=7.00,Z=9.00]"
"32"      
I want the output like this